# sorting one list based on the results of python in descending order

Tags: python, list, sorting

Input

```
a= (92, 93, 94, 95)
b= [0.76, 0.46, 0.56,0.64]
```

required is the sorting of list a based on list b in descending order

```
a= [92, 95, 94, 93]
b= [0.76, 0.64, 0.56, 0.46]
```

I used

```
a,b = zip(*sorted(zip(a,b), key=operator.itemgetter(0), reverse=True))
```

I tried to use it to sort in ascending order and then try to use another list to write in the reverse order.

The error is :

```
key=operator.itemgetter(0), reverse=True))
NameError: name 'operator' is not defined
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error that you see is because you need to import the `operator` module. Even doing that does not fix the problem though.

Instead you can do it like this:

```
b, a = zip(*sorted(zip(b,a), reverse=True))
```

For your data:

```
>>> a = [92, 93, 94, 95]
>>> b = [0.76, 0.46, 0.56,0.64]
>>> b, a = zip(*sorted(zip(b,a), reverse=True))
>>> a
(92, 95, 94, 93)
>>> b
(0.76, 0.64, 0.56, 0.46)
```

This gives you *tuples*. If you really want/need lists:

```
>>> a = [92, 93, 94, 95]
>>> b = [0.76, 0.46, 0.56,0.64]
>>> b, a = (list(x) for x in zip(*sorted(zip(b,a), reverse=True)))
>>> a
[92, 95, 94, 93]
>>> b
[0.76, 0.64, 0.56, 0.46]
```

Comment: @mhwake   ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack

Comment: @HamadHassan: really? It works for me in both Python 2 and 3. What version of Python are you using? Which example were you testing?

Comment: it may be an error on my part, what I see on screen is (92, 93, 94, 95)
[0.76, 0.46, 0.56, 0.64]  the first one is not a list? i tried even printing a[0] but getting index out of bound!

Comment: I am using python 2.7

Comment: @HamadHassan: definitely an error at your end. It works for me in 2.7. It's clear in the answer, there are 2 variants: the first returns _tuples_ (_both_ `a` and `b`). The second returns _lists_ ( again _both_ `a` and `b`). Can't see how you are getting one of each type.

Comment: I am talking about the input.. The input is in that form... the output should be list! I am sorry for that.

Comment: @HamadHassan: oh, I see, you changed the question so that `a` is now a tuple. Well, the second version returns lists, and it works with any combination of equal length sequences including tuples and lists. So what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Did you `import operator`?

Not that it is needed:

```
z = list(zip(a, b))
z = sorted(z, key=lambda i: i[1], reverse=True)
a, b = list(zip(*z))
```

Comment: TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: If you `zip()` the lists in the other order you don't need the `lambda` at all. Also it doesn't work (you need to pass the key function as a keyword argument).